# Proof of limits

Tags: calculus

I was wondering is there another way of proving that limit of $sin(x)/x = 1$ as $x$ approaches $0$ without using l'hospital rule but using equivalence relations. I was reading a calculus book and i see that there some functions that are equivalence to one another like $sin(x)$ is equivalent to $x$.

Comment: Well, (depending on what equivalence you're talking about) that would be circular argument. We say that $\sin x \sim x$ exactly because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: What does your book mean that $\sin x$ is equivalent to $x$?

Comment: By 'equivalence relation' do you mean the fact that ($\alpha(x),\alpha_1(x),\beta(x),\beta_1(x)$ having limits $0$ when $x\to a$): $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\alpha(x)}{\alpha_1(x)}=1, \lim_{x\to a}\frac{\beta(x)}{\beta_1(x)}=1\implies \lim_{x\to a}\frac{\alpha(x)}{\beta(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\alpha_1(x)}{\beta_1(x)}$?

Comment: More like using little $o$ and big $O$ as equivalence relations

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go so far as to say that any "equivalence" that $\sin(x)$ and $x$ have is useful here. The ratio of their limit at $0$ is $1$, but other than that, they're very different functions. If your definition of "equivalent" is that the ratio of their limit at $0$ is $1$, then you can't use equivalence in your proof, because that would be circular.

You can prove this without any advanced techniques using the Squeeze Theorem. In particular, when $x$ is close to $0$, $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ can be squeezed between $cosx$ and $1$. See [this PDF](http://math.ucsb.edu/~jcs/SqueezeTheorem.pdf) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: There is a definition of function 'equivalence' - $(\sin x \sim x\text{ when }x\to 0)\iff \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: yeah thanks man i appreciated

Comment: @user314 I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user146269 See [this M.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/107671) for a geometrical proof.